# List items alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a list and in Firefox it looks like this: http://cl.ly/2Og9 but in Safari it looks like this: http://cl.ly/2PLT

Here's the code for the list. Very simple:

```
#footerwrap #footer-left li {
    background: url(images/common/list-item.gif) no-repeat 0px 10px;
    padding: 4px 10px 8px 15px;
    font: normal 12px Verdana;
}
```

What do I need to do to get it to align properly like it does in Firefox? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind it was a stupid thing. The list didn't have a ul tag around the li's. Thanks!